# How to get the value of an data-* attribute from a dynamically created select in a table when I change an option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the value of an data-* attribute from a dynamically created select in a table when I change an option. I am getting an "Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined".

The creating HTML is:

```
html += "<td style='width : 1%; white-space: nowrap;'><select name='parRating'>"
for (let i = 0; i <= paraArray; i++) {
    html += "<option name='parRatingOption' data-index='" + i + "' value='" + parIdArray[i] + "'>" + parRatingArray[i] + "</option>"
};
html += "</select></td>";
```

The option change catch is:

```
$('#showPatientPARForm').on( 'change', 'select[name="parRating"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("this.value: " + this.value);//works
    alert("this.data-index: " + this.data-index);//Uncaught ReferenceError: index is not defined
});
```

I have also tried:

alert("this.attr('data-index'): " + $(this).attr("data-index")); //undefined

Comment: `paraArray` is this array or a numeric value ?

Comment: @DankDizaster paraArray is a numerical value containing the number of values in the array. I will rename it to parArraySize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure to target the `data-attribute` correctly,
the value of the option gets returned from the parent selector (`select`), but the option itself needs to be accessed differently.
Use `dataset` to target data attributes.

```js
let paraArray = ['one','two','three'];
let parIdArray = ['idOne','idTwo','idThree'];
let parRatingArray = [1,2,3];

let html = '';
html += "<td><select name='parRating'>";
for (let i = 0; i < paraArray.length; i++) {
    html += "<option name='parRatingOption' data-index='" + i + "' value='" + parIdArray[i] + "'>" + parRatingArray[i] + "</option>";
}

html += "</select></td>";

$('#showPatientPARForm table').append(html);

$('#showPatientPARForm').on( 'change', 'select[name="parRating"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   
    alert("this.value: " + this.value);//works
    
    // select the data attribute correctly:
    //alert(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].dataset.index);
    alert(this.options.selectedIndex)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showPatientPARForm">
  <table></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. This displays "0 value=". I am expecting and integer between 0 and n.

Comment: Hi, the answer is within your answer; being, this.options.selectedIndex returns an integer between 0 ... n. Please update your answer and I will upvote and accept.

Comment: @Glyn, it returns an index/integer based on the amount of items in ```paraArray```, ```data-index='" + i + "'```, which represents the ```i```. Not sure what you expect to get, please explain?

Comment: I just created some 'dummy arrays', since I don't know what your arrays look like. The issue you weren't able to access the data attribute for a selected item should be resolved, no?

Comment: alert(this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].dataset.index); returns "0 value=". alert(this.options.selectedIndex) returns "0"; which is what I want. So if you adjust your answer can accept it.

Comment: Updated the answer :)